# Using try-catch in PHP how to go to finally without throw an Exception?

Tags: php

About the following code, how can I go to finally without throw an Exception in PHP?

```
try {
  $db = DataSource::getConnection();
  if (some condition here is TRUE) { 
     // go to finally without throw an exception 
  }
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->saveMyData();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
} finally {
  $db = null;
}
```

Comment: In your example there is no need for finally. What is your XY problem? Why do you want to do this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this, but here's an option:

```php
try {
    if (TRUE){
        goto ugh;
    }
    echo "\ndid not break";
    ugh:
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "\ndid catch";
} finally {
    echo "\ni'm so tired";
}
```

I strongly encourage against using a `goto`. I think it's just really easy for code to get sloppy & confusing if you're using `goto`.

I'd recommend:

```php
try {
    if (TRUE){
        echo "\nThat's better";
    } else {
       echo "\ndid not break";
    }
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "\ndid catch";
} finally {
    echo "\ni'm so tired";
}
```

You just wrap the rest of the `try` into an `else` in order to skip it.

---

Another option could be to declare a finally function, call that, and return.

```
//I'm declaring as a variable, as to not clutter the declared methods
//If you had one method across scripts, naming it `function doFinally(){}` could work well
$doFinally = function(){};
try {
    if (TRUE){
        $doFinally();
        return;
    }
    echo "\ndid not break";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "\ndid catch";
} finally {
    $doFinally();
}
```

If you needed to continue the script, you could declare `$doFinally` something like:

```php
$doFinally = function($reset=FALSE){
    static $count;
    if ($reset===TRUE){
        $count = 0;
        return;
    } else if ($count===NULL)$count = 0;
    else if ($count>0)return;
}
```

Then after the `finally` block, you could call `$doFinally(TRUE)` to reset it for the next `try`/`catch`

Comment: Thank you! I used to use this "goto" many years ago in Clipper, I didn't know exists "goto" in PHP! I asked because I do some checks into "try", despite occur some error that can be thrown, some times I need to "return" and not "throw Exception" but execute what exists into "finally" before "return". Let's use a simple example, suppose close the connection into "finally". Into a condition in "try", when not satisfacted, I need to "return" and "close the connection" that exists into "finally". How to not duplicate this code? I think there is no way, we need to use some method, or repeat code.

Comment: @RodrigoGuariento, updated the answer. Declaring a new function could be the way to go.